# create multiple block volume per instance in oci using terraform

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I try to create multiple block volumes per compute instance. I can have multiple instances based on variable:

```
resource "oci_core_instance" "cache" {
  count = var.instance_counts["cache"]

  # Instance details
  compartment_id      = oci_identity_compartment.core_compartment.id
  availability_domain = data.oci_identity_availability_domain.example.name
  display_name        = "${var.cache_server_name}${count.index + 1}"
  shape               = var.cache_server_shape

  # Define shape configuration for OCPU and memory
  shape_config {
    ocpus         = var.shape_config_cache_ocpus
    memory_in_gbs = var.shape_config_cache_memory
  }

  create_vnic_details {
    subnet_id        = oci_core_subnet.public_subnet.id
    assign_public_ip = false # Set to true if you want a public IP assigned
  }

  source_details {
    source_type = var.source_details_source_type
    source_id   = var.cache_server_image
  }
```

I need to go through each instance and create 1 or multiple volumes based on the variable:

```
resource "oci_core_volume" "cache_volume" {
  count = var.block_volume_number

  compartment_id      = oci_identity_compartment.core_compartment.id
  availability_domain = data.oci_identity_availability_domain.example.name

  dynamic "cache_volume_info" {
    for_each = oci_core_instance.cache
    content {
      compartment_id       = instance_info.value.compartment_id
      availability_domain  = instance_info.value.availability_domain

      display_name  = "${instance_info.value.display_name}-volume-${instance_info.key + 1}-${count.index % 2 + 1}"
      size_in_gbs  = 50
      vpus_per_gb  = 30
    }
  }
}
```

For example:
When the block volume is defined at 4 and the count of computed instances is defined at 1, I want to create volumes this way:

- instance-1-volume-1
- instance-1-volume-2
- instance-1-volume-3
- instance-1-volume-4

When the block volume is defined at 3 and the count of computed instances is defined at 2, I want to create volumes this way:

- instance-1-volume-1
- instance-1-volume-2
- instance-2-volume-1
- instance-2-volume-2
- instance-3-volume-1
- instance-3-volume-2

Even though I tried several things, I faced several errors like this: "Blocks of type "cache_volume_info" are not expected here."